# Magento 2 override default.phtml and items.phtml in new order email

Tags: magento, magento2

I made a module that overrides default.phtml and i put and product image in there, and it works fine!

I made this sales_email_orders_renderers.xml to overide the default.phtml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder" as="default" template="EmizenTech_SalesEmail::email/items/order/default.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

The original is in vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/

But how to also override the items.phtml in an other folder?

/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/

Do i need to make an other xml or can i put some tags in the existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to your theme and create folder
Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order

then
download default.phtml file

from
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order

then paste here
Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order your theme.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in module and not in theme? Because modular development is more robust in modern techs.

Comment: @GhulamAkbar, did you get any solution for module